# How to Audit log user clicks in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I've been looking for a way in Hybris 6.6 to log user's clicks or more specifically the links a user clicks while he's on the site.

I've seen the audit-config.xml there are several atomic, virtual and reference attributes.
The audit log which is generated from backoffice has only lower level of detail. in short I need to know what certain user is interested in so that I could personalize accordingly without using 'Sap Hana' stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not very familiar with this topic. But maybe I can point you to the right keywords.

There is a module that SAP hybris offers for this purpose. It is called BTG (behavior targeting groups?). It gathers information on what a customer might like and offers mechanisms to personalize the website according to a customers interest. Have a look at the hybris documentation to find out more about BTG.

Also a lot of customers use Google Analytics to track customer behavior on their homepage. But you have to include the implementation manually. It might not be the right tool for this purpose since it is more used to gather statistics of your website and less to gather information about individuals. Additionally I don't know a way to use the information to enhance the presentation of you website.

Comment: Couldn't find such module in hybris, but thanks anyway

Comment: Apparently it is now called Advanced personalization. Refer to this https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sap-hybris-commerce-advance-personalization-use-cases-tarangg-goel or this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sap_hybris/sap_hybris_personalization.htm